# Get total video bytes / video bytes loaded with youtube javascript api on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, api, webview, youtube

I am embedding a YT Video in a UIWebView on iOS 5 using the YT Api to embed the video in an iframe. Evereything is working fine: the system player pops up while my app keeps running and getting callbacks from the webview. but determining, how many bytes were loaded and how many are available. How can i determine the total number of bytes and the number of bytes of a particular video, using iframe embedded in a UIWebView and the Javascript youtube API?

here is how i initialize my player:

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', { height: '120', width: '120', videoId: 'lUj4mYPFW4U', events: {  'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange, 'onPlaybackQualityChange' : onPlaybackQualityChange  } });
}
```

and here how i try to get information on the bytes:

```
function getVideoBytesProgress(){
    var s = player.getVideoBytesLoaded() + "/" + player.getVideoBytesTotal();
    return s;
}
```

getVideoBytesTotal() always returns 1000, whereas getVideoBytesLoaded() always returns 0. Is there a way, to get my desired information? on a desktop browser, this works fine. what am i doing wrong on ios?

Comment: did you find anything, i have the same problem?

Comment: No, i did not find a direct solution. But, however, you can get the current download status as a rational number between 0 and 1 using `player.getVideoLoadedFraction()`

Comment: but if video is paused i always get the same value with player.getVideoLoadedFraction(). And the only way to refresh that value that i found is to .play() and .pause().